# Windows: make browsers do a DNS-lookup even when the Computer is offline

Tags: windows, browser, dns

I use a local DNS-Server ([MicroDNS](http://samiam.org/software/microdns.html)) which I set via netsh to redirect any query to my own page. A little webserver running inside my software answering something like "this page is not whitelisted". It works when connected to the Internet but does not work when offline. The Browsers stop looking up the DNS.

How could I make Browsers go to my page, whatever I enter in the address line, WHEN OFFLINE?

Comment: @MadBurn you misread my question: the DNS-Server is running localy to filter. He does give the right answer (127.0.0.1). My problem is, that Chrome or Firefox stop asking my DNS-Server when there is no connection through a Network Device.

Comment: I understand now, my apologies.